# Is there a unique identifier for merchants in Plaid transactions?

Tags: transactions, plaid

I have merchant-specific data and images I want to show per transaction but am finding it difficult to match a registered company to a Plaid merchant.

Is there any list of Plaid-supported merchants? or a unique merchant/registration id?

I am worried that the merchant name may differ per purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no unique identifier for merchants -- merchant identity is not information that's provided by institutions and merchants in a consistent, cross-institution way. The closest equivalent, and what I would recommend using for this case, is the `merchant_name` field, which is Plaid's attempt to extract a clean and consistent merchant name from raw transaction description data. However, this field doesn't necessarily have the level of precision or consistency that would be implied by using a unique identifier.

Comment: Hello Alex@PlaidDeveloperRelations, I suspect there's room for improvement here.  I am currently writing a method call "guess_merchant" based on Plaid's transaction metadata.  With my limited data set I've found some very obvious ways to figure out the merchant with ~90+% accuracy (ballparkin here).  One would think Plaid could do the same to a higher degree of accuracy.  By comparison, Mint/Intuit do this extremely well with presumably similar base data.